# Curl & Wget returning response, Browser times out

Tags: linux, browser, timeout, wget, redhat

I am sending requests to a specific server on a cloud:

```
wget --header="Host: example.com" http://x.x.x.x:80/
curl -i -H"Host: example.com" http://x.x.x.x:80/
```

And it returns exactly as expected (a simple static file).  However, when I try and access it in a browser, the request times out.  I can't imagine it would be a user agent header issue, but then again, I don't really know what else it would be.

It isn't going to a load balancer or anything, should be going directly to the site.  Any ideas on why this might be happening?  I have my hosts file set to go to that specific IP address.

Thanks

Comment: you could try to do further tests by appending more headers and see when it fails. You can get the default headers sent by firefox using running `ncat --listen 8081` in a terminal and simultanously navigating firefox to `http://localhost:8081`. Try to add these on after the other to wget/curl and see what happens. Also try a terminal browser like `w3m` or `links`. Maybe you're also just a victim of bad timing.

Comment: Dont you have proxy? Check env | grep proxy? Maybe its set only in the browser or only in the terminal?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're specifying an IP address in wget/curl but a hostname in your browser.  This creates additional variables in the test and we can't troubleshoot the results.  (You need to better [control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control) the test.)

Try replicating your browser logic on the command line:

```
wget http://example.com/
```

This performs the same test as you want in your browser with `wget`.

**If it works**, you have a configuration issue with your browser (or perhaps any proxy settings inherited from your OS).

**If it does not work**, you likely have an issue with your hosts file.

You can also try the test in reverse; find some browser add-on that lets you specify/alter arbitrary headers or that explicitly lets you set the hostname separately from the URL and then go to `http://x.x.x.x:80/` as you did with wget/curl.